# Integration Remote Weblogic 12c JMS broker with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, weblogic

I'm trying to integrate remote JMS broker which provide by Weblogic 12c to my Spring boot application. And I'm facing with **Runtime Exception Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo** when sending my message to message queue.

Here is what's i did :

1. add dependencies **spring-jms**, **spring-boot-starter-activemq** and **wlsclient** ( the librariy to help connect to JMS-Server which I got from lib folder of running Weblogic server) into my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>wls</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlsclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/wlclient.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

2. Add Configurations to initialize connection, JNDI Template, JMS Template..etc

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${spring.jms.url}")
    private String jmsUrl;
    @Value("${spring.jms.username}")
    private String jmsUser;
    @Value("${spring.jms.password}")
    private String jmsPassword;
    @Value("${spring.jms.connectionFactoryName}")
    private String jmsConnFactoryName;

    private Properties getJNDIProperties(){
        final Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        jndiProps.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        jndiProps.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jmsUrl);
        if (jmsUser != null && !jmsUser.isEmpty()) {
            jndiProps.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, jmsUser);
        }
        if (jmsPassword != null && !jmsPassword.isEmpty()) {
            jndiProps.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, jmsPassword);
        }
        return jndiProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        // JNDI connection factory name stored in weblogic.
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = lookupByJndiTemplate(jmsConnFactoryName, QueueConnectionFactory.class);
        logger.info("connectionFactory " + connectionFactory);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(getJNDIProperties());
        logger.info("jndiTemplate " + jndiTemplate);
        return jndiTemplate;
    }

    protected <T> T lookupByJndiTemplate(String jndiName, Class<T> requiredType) {

        try {
            Object located = jndiTemplate().lookup(jndiName);
            logger.info("lookupByJndiTemplate located " + located);
            if (located == null) {
                throw new NameNotFoundException("JNDI object with [" + jndiName + "] not found");
            }
            return (T) located;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected final <T> T lookup(String jndiName, Class<T> requiredType) {

        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(getJNDIProperties());
            Object located = initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
            if (located == null) {
                throw new NameNotFoundException("JNDI object with [" + jndiName + "] not found");
            }
            return (T) located;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setPubSubDomain(false); // false for a Queue, true for a Topic
        logger.info("Jms template " + template);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> containerFactory(){
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

And here is my JMSService to usage JMSTemplate to send message event:

```
@Service
public class JMSService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSService.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public boolean send(String jndiName, JMSMsgModel jmsMsgModel){
        try{
            WrapperMessage message = new WrapperMessage(jndiName, new Date().getTime(),jmsMsgModel);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(jndiName,message);
            logger.info("Message sent " + message);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Error while send event message via JMS " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}

class WrapperMessage {
    private String jndi;
    private Long issueAt;
    private Object message;

    public WrapperMessage(String jndi, Long issueAt, Object message) {
        this.jndi = jndi;
        this.issueAt = issueAt;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getJndi() {
        return jndi;
    }

    public void setJndi(String jndi) {
        this.jndi = jndi;
    }

    public Long getIssueAt() {
        return issueAt;
    }

    public void setIssueAt(Long issueAt) {
        this.issueAt = issueAt;
    }

    public Object getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Object message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I got Exception while application try to send message via **convertAndSend** method of jmsTemplate :

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at com.vnpt.sync.residents.service.services.JMSService.send(JMSService.java:24)
    at com.vnpt.sync.residents.service.services.ApplicationService.save(ApplicationService.java:109)
    at com.vnpt.sync.residents.service.controllers.ApplicationRegisterController.registerApplication(ApplicationRegisterController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:133)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:69)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createDestination(JMSSession.java:3457)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createQueue(JMSSession.java:2746)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.createQueue(WLSessionImpl.java:945)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:585)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:400)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:436)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:67)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:227)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:95)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher._DispatcherImpl_Stub.dispatchSyncTranFuture(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:390)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadException(ORBUtilSystemException.java:7004)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:988)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:822)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:681)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:431)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:120)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1961)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:603)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:199)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:915)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:603)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:199)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:915)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:738)
    at weblogic.utils.io.FilteringObjectInputStream.resolveClass(FilteringObjectInputStream.java:41)
    at weblogic.common.internal.ReplacerObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ReplacerObjectInputStream.java:51)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1830)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2121)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:441)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.readExternal(WLContextImpl.java:608)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.readExternal(WLEventContextImpl.java:459)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1039)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    ... 115 more
```

What's wrong with my code and how can I fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: Which exact weblogic server version are you using ?
This class is not present in wlclient.jar but in wlthint3client.jar

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelCollin, I fixed it by use wlclient.jar which exported from my weblogic server to help initialize connection to weblogic server address.